# stata's cmp - how does it correlate models?

Tags: stata

How does stata's cmp correlates the 4 equations in the final output of a command line like the following

```
cmp (wage = educ city) (lfp = kids618 educ) (age = educ repwage)  (city = kids618 huswage), indicators(lfp $cmp_probit city $cmp_probit)
```

Please explain a bit of the math behind this.

Comment: If you `search cmp` in Stata you will see accessible references.  Otherwise this seems off-topic to me.